Grounding Lug Straight To Chassis
Connecting some thicker gauge cable to my trailer to ground neutral for the 12v DC system.  The current 8AWG wire uses a receptacle style lug where the wires are inserted and the that receptacle is screwed into the chassis.  Since my new stuff is 1 AWG cable, I'm thinking it's easiest to just bolt the copper lug straight to the chassis rather than using some kind of mechanical lug with a receptacle for the wires.
Are there are reasons I should avoid bolting the lug straight to the chassis, and use another piece of grounding hardware?
Here is an example of what I could use instead of bolting straight to the chassis with the copper lug: mechanical lug.  No matter what, I will protect the connection and use corrosion inhibitor.

I'm confused by your description of the two options. It sounds like option 1 is to attach a lug to the wire and bolt the lug to the chassis, and option 2 is to attach a lug to the wire and bolt the lug to the chassis. What's the difference between the two options? I wonder if you're using the word "lug" differently than how I use the word "lug," because to me, all lugs are "some kind of mechanical lug with a receptacle for the wires." Perhaps when you say "the copper lug," what you mean is the plain copper wire without a lug.

I should have said, which is better, a screw based receptacle style connector or a copper crimped lug.  They are both basically lugs or connectors.

You can use lugs for a chassis connection. What you show is about the same as a mechanical lug, the only difference is one is a crimp on connector and one is a screw/crimp which is less reliable in my experience.
The real thing is how much current does the cable need to carry and will the connector get self heating due to contact resistance, heating should be avoided.

Thank you.  I guess my question was really: is there an advantage to one over the other?  They are about the same since they are both just metal connectors, but I figured someone here would have a response about why one option is preferred.  Other factor is do you already own one connector and hence do not need to buy something new!
